# Write a for/while loop with "if/else" in a more elegant way?

Tags: matlab, if-statement, for-loop, vectorization

I've written this code :

`A` is a `nXm` matrix

```
[nA, mA] = size(A);

currentVector(nA,mA) = 0;
for i = 1: nA
    for j = 1 : mA
        if A (i,j) ~= 0
            currentVector(i,j) = ceil(log10( abs(A(i,j)) ));
        else
            currentVector(i,j) = 0;
        end
    end
end
```

How can I write the above code in a more "matlab" way ?

Are there any shortcuts for if/else and for loops ? for example in `C` :

```
int a = 0;
int b = 10;
a = b > 100 ? b : a;
```

Those `if/else` conditions keeps reminding me of `C` and `Java` .

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
%# initialize a matrix of zeros of same size as A
currentVector = zeros(size(A));

%# find linear-indices of elements where A is non-zero
idx = (A ~= 0);

%# fill output matrix at those locations with the corresponding elements from A
%# (we apply a formula "ceil(log10(abs(.)))" to those elements then store them)
currentVector(idx) = ceil(log10( abs(A(idx)) ));
```

Comment: Best solution, but I guess you should put some explanation. ;-)

Comment: @kay: done. Feel free to add references to relevant sections in the MATLAB documentation (I'm sure there are plenty discussing writing vectorized code, and performing matrix indexing)

Comment: @Amro: Amazing, I'll use that from now on . Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
currentVector =  ceil(log10(abs(A)));
currentVector(A == 0) = 0;
```

Note: in Matlab it is totally legal to apply log on zeros - the result is: -inf.