# Vectorization of nested loops and if statements in MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization

I am fairly new to the concept of vectorization in MATLAB so please excuse my naivety in this regard. I was trying to vectorize the following MATLAB code which includes if statements within nested for loops:

```
h = zeros(dimV);
for a = 1 : dimV
    for b = 1 : dimV

        if a ~= b && C(a,b) == 1
           h(a,b) = C(a,b)*exp(-1i*A(a,b)*L(a,b))*(sin(k*L(a,b)))^-1;

        else if a == b

                for m = 1 : dimV
                    if m ~= a && C(a,m) == 1
                       h(a,b) = h(a,b) - C(a,m)*cot(k*L(a,m));
                    end
                end
            end

        end
    end
end
```

Here the variable `dimV` specifies the size of the matrix `h` and is fairly large, of the order of 100, and `C` is a symmetric square matrix (previously defined) of size `dimV` all of whose off-diagonal elements are either 0 or 1 and the diagonal elements are necesarrily 0. The elements of matrix `L` are also zero in the same positions as the zeros of the matrix `C`. Following the vectorization techniques that I found [on this website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859990/write-a-for-while-loop-with-if-else-in-a-more-elegant-way?rq=1) and [here](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~marios/matlab/Matlab%20Tricks.pdf), I was able to vectorize the code, albeit partially, and my MWE is as follows:

```
h = zeros(dimV);

idx = (C  == 1);
h(idx) = C(idx).*exp(-1i*A(idx).*L(idx)).*(sin(k*L(idx))).^-1;

for a = 1:dimV;   

    m = 1 : dimV;
    m = m(C(a,:) == 1);
    h(a,a) = - sum (C(a,m).*cot(k*L(a,m)));

end
```

My main problem is in converting the `for` loop in the variable `a` to a vector as I need the individual values of `a` to address the diagonal elements of `h`. I compared the evaluation time of both the code blocks using the MATLAB profiler and the latter version is only marginally faster and the improvement in efficiency is really insignificant. In fact the profiler showed that the line allocating the values to `h(a,a)` takes up nearly 50% of the execution time in the second case. So I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to rewrite the above code using the appropriate vectorization schemes, which would help improve its efficiency. I am really in a bit of bother about this and any I would be greatly appreciative of any help in this regard. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vectorized Code -

```
diag_ind = 1:dimV+1:numel(C);
C_neq1 = C~=1;

parte1_2 = (sin(k.*L)).^-1;
parte1_2(C_neq1 & (L==0))=0;
parte1 = exp(-1i.*A.*L).*parte1_2;
parte1(C_neq1)=0;

h = parte1;

parte2 = cot(k*L);
parte2(C_neq1)=0;
parte2(diag_ind)=0;
h(diag_ind) = - sum(parte2,2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately, this does not work universally. There is a slight complication because the elements of the matrix `L` can also be 0 and the above-mentioned code results in the `h` matrix elements being defined as `NaN` at those positions (owing to the `sin` and `cot` functions), whereas they should actually be 0 at such positions. You will notice that this problem does not arise with the original code that I posted. I have also made an edit to my question to emphasize this point.

Comment: @UserXeTex Can we have `L` as zero where `A` isn't zero?

Comment: I'm really very sorry for the confusion and the inadvertent error in my previous edit. Just to clarify, an element of the matrix `L` is zero if and only if the corresponding element of the matrix `C` is zero. The elements of the matrix `A` can assume any values, independent of `C` and `L`.

Comment: @UserXeTex Sorry it looks messy, gotta clean that up! Also, I would be curious on how much of improvement you would be getting with this one on your dataset.

Comment: The cleaned up code is somewhat more efficient than the previous version you posted. The block that I wanted to vectorize is a part of a bigger function and I only have the evaluation times for the whole program. For my data set, my MWE implementation resulted in an evaluation time of 370.021967 seconds for the function whereas the implementation using your code takes 288.294048 seconds. So it is a really good improvement considering that this function is called a large number of times.

Comment: @UserXeTex Thanks for the benchmark results. I did few of my own benchmarking on these codes and observed a 4-5x improvement with the vectorized code over the original nested loops version with `dimV` ranging from `100` to `4K`. So I can guestimate that other parts of the bigger function are dragging it slower. Good luck anyway!